# FCM Push for iOS error InvalidRegistration

Tags: php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notifications through PHP script via `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to iOS App.

Currently I'm using following test `PHP` script.

```
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$serverKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$title = "Title";
$body = "Body of the message";
$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
//Send the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//Close request
if ($response === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

However, I am receiving following error message when I try to run script via browser.

```
{"multicast_id":5417898622260949101,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

But when I use the same device token from FCM console, it is working without any issues.

I have tried many PHP scripts on the internet, but end up with the same results, what would be the issue here ?

Any help would be highly appreciate.

Comment: According to the documentation ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes ), "InvalidRegistration" refers to a malformed value. Can you make sure that there are no additional characters or white spaces in the value for your registration token?

Comment: Please also note that you're currently using the Legacy HTTP Protocol - if you can, please consider implementing this with the HTTP v1 Protocol ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages ), which will ensure that your script stays future proof.

Comment: @jeromegamez I'm using string to pass the token, there are not any additional characters for sure. But i used trim to make sure there is no additional spaces append somehow at the final step when I make the array.
Regarding the second point , I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The token you are using does not seem to be a valid registration token for FCM, hence the InvalidRegistration error.

Comment: when I am using the same token with FCM console, it works. So token should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$title = 'Title'; 
$message = 'hello message';
$notification =[ 
                    "text" => "Test",
                    'badge' => "1",
                    'sound' => 'shutter.mp3',
                    "android_channel_id"=>"test01",
                    'body'=>$message,
                    'icon'=>'notif_icn',
                    'title'=>$title,
                    'priority'=>'high',
                    'vibrate'=> 1,
                    'alert'=> $message
                ];

$msg = [
            'message'=> $message,
            'title'=> $title
        ];

$fields =[
            "content_available" => true,
            "priority" => "high",
            'registration_ids'=> $deviceToken,
            'data'=> $msg
        ];

$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,'Content-Type: application/json');    
if ($headers){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($response === FALSE) {
        die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: gives me the same error, {"multicast_id":9134981740272359930,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}